# Java: Unique hashCode() on Immutable Objects through static counter

Tags: java, equals, immutability, hashcode

I have a very large `Set` of Immutable Objects so I am thinking of assigning a unique hashcode to them at construction time.

```
private static int counter = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

private final double foo;
private final double bar;
private final int hashCode;

public MyImmutableObject(double foo, double bar)
{
    counter++;
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
    this.hashCode = counter;
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return this.hashCode;
}

   /**
    * Unneeded override of equals since its the same as in
    * Object, but shown for demonstration purposes. 
    */
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    return this == obj;
}
```

This way, I can achieve the highest possible dispersity of keys, since I will have 2<sup>32</sup> unique keys. Of course, this also means that no two objects of this type will ever be equal, since an object will only be equal to itself.

edit: The Objects are also used as keys in `Map`s.

Is this possible to do? Are there hidden traps I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible to do? Are there hidden traps I missed?

Thread safety, for one thing? You could use `AtomicInteger` to get round that, of course.

Then there's also the pointlessness of it, really. The built-in hash code is going to be *pretty close* to unique without you doing any extra work (and taking an extra 4 bytes per object). Given that you're not changing the meaning of equality (it's still basically reference equality) I can't see that there's any good reason to do this.

Comment: That, and even with perfectly unique hash codes, hash tables will still have collisions -- since you're basically modding the hash codes by some value.  There's no perfect way to avoid collisions, not even the way the OP describes.  Given that, why add the extra complexity?

Comment: I always create hashCodes with Objects.hashCode() from guava and I assume I get some collisions because I notice about 20% improvement in a process that uses Set/Map with these objects. Not caching the value dramatically decreases performance according to my tests and profiling.

Comment: @AlexanderKaratarakis: I wasn't suggesting using `Objects.hashCode` - it's not clear what you'd hash here anyway, given that no fields are involved in the equality test. I'm suggesting removing the `hashCode` and `equals` entirely. Just use the built-in implementation, as you're only looking for reference equality.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Even if the bucket collides, it's still quick to look through the saved hash codes to find ones which are *actually* equal, so you don't need to call `equals` for objects which don't have the same exact 32-bit hash code.

Comment: That's true, at least for the built-in JDK hash tables.  (Not for Guava's `ImmutableSet` and `ImmutableMap`, though.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Oh, do they "forget" the real hash codes, and just rely on the bucket? Can't say I've looked yet, although now I'm intrigued.

Comment: Heh.  `ImmutableSet` uses an open addressing approach which doesn't really have individual "buckets."  That reduces memory consumption by ~60%, but for well-designed immutable element classes, it performs at least as well as `HashSet`.  (Indeed, I'm working on a project to cut memory consumption by another 30-40%.)  `ImmutableMap` uses a more traditional closed-addressing, linked-list approach, but it still saves ~20% on memory by omitting the cached hash code.

Comment: @JonSkeet Tried removing `hashCode` entirely, but running time was doubled :/. The original implementation has a normal cached hashcode calculated through `Objects.hashCode(foo, bar)` and a normal `equals` method. There is a noticeable performance improvement when doing this "trick" with the `hashCode`. Also, since it was mentioned the process mostly uses `ImmutableSet` and `ImmutableMap`.

Comment: @AlexanderKaratarakis: If your "original implementation" uses a traditional `equals` method, then the code you've provided is completely unrepresentative. The distinction about whether you need value equality or reference equality is *crucially important*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant that the Immutable class has a standard `hashCode` and `equals` that relies on foo and bar. Messing with the `hashCode` is an idea that seems to speed up things. Since I am messing with the `hashCode`, I need to preserve the `equals` contract that equal objects must have equal `hashcode`s. This can only be guaranteed if the object is the same, hence the reference equality.

Comment: This also means that with this approach I cannot create equal Objects even if I supply exactly the same `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: @AlexanderKaratarakis: Right. So the question is, what *behaviour* do you want? Do you *really* want reference equality? If so, I'd still recommend removing `equals` and `hashCode` entirely. If not, implement `equals` and `hashCode` according to your real requirements.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Just re-read what the default implementation of `hashCode` does and I see what you mean. Since it is based on memory address, it should have roughly the same behaviour as the counter-based `hashCode`. For some reason it doesn't though, `Object.hashCode` provides a much better `hashCode` (half the execution time from default `hashCode`) and the suggested counter-based `hashCode` is even better (about 20% less than `Objects.hashCode`). This may be an isolated case (I have only 1 "test" case at the moment after all), so I will stick to the traditional `equals` & `hashCode` for now.

Comment: @LouisWasserman (Referencing the first comment). Since I can never avoid collisions I may have been "lucky" in my test case, so the results may not representative.